# URL is not getting username from route in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to show author page by the URL: `domian.com/author/page/{username}`.

Here is the route:

```
Route::get('author/page/{username}', 'FrontendAuthorController@index');
```

Here is the controller (FrontendAuthorController@index):

```
public function index($username)
{
    $user = BasicInfo::where('username', $username)->first(); 

    //'username' is a field of BasicInfo Model. 
    //BasicInfo belongs to User model. 
    //So, we can get user id by $user->user_id according to eloquent rule. 

    $author = User::findOrFail($user->user_id);

    return view('frontend.author', compact('author'));
}
```

But I get this message in view

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

If I try to get view with this route `domian.com/author/page/{username}/{id}` with this parameter `function index($username, $id)` then I get the view! I don't want to show id in route/url. how can I solve this?

Comment: Well, you *are* querying the User model with a findOrFail, so it does seem that it's failing. If you do a `dd($user->user_id)` then you might get more information.

Comment: can you please share the table structure

Comment: @LinusJuhlin I am trying to get value by dd($user->user_id) but whenever enter the url it directly showing page not found message. maybe they are not getting route, so controller is not executing.

Comment: @Manojkiran.A 

BasicInfo Model contains-> 

'user_id', 'user_image', 'user_cover_image', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'display_name', 'username', 'dob', 'biography',

User Model Contains-->
'email', 'password',

Comment: Did you check the value of the $username and $user?

Comment: Yes, they were working perfectly when the route was `domian.com/author/page/{username}/{id}`. Browser started showing 404 error when I modified the route to `domian.com/author/page/{username}`.

Comment: That is strange, did you check, that the method is called, when the url is /author/page/{username}? To debug, you should remove the complete code from the method and return "works". Then check again for 404 error.

Comment: Tip : While working in local server or even in production while debugging please turn set `APP_DEBUG=true` in .env file

Comment: It might not help but it could be worth running `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: @MosharofZitu Check my answer you need your route like `Route::get('author/page/{username}/{id?}`, 'FrontendAuthorController@index'). Adding `?` makes that parameter optional

Answer (score 0):

give name to route

```
Route::get('author/page/{username}', 'FrontendAuthorController@index')->name('author_page');
```

then check route :

**php artisan route:list**

test with below function :

```
public function index(Request $request,$username)
{
   return response($username);
}
```

then update ,

```
public function index($username)
{
    if(isset($username)){
       $user = BasicInfo::where('username', $username)->first(); 
       if($user){
           $author = User::findOrFail($user->user_id);
           return view('frontend.author', compact('author'));
       }else{
          // user not found , redirect to home page or 404
         abort(404);
       }
    }else{
          // $username not set , redirect to home page or 404
          abort(404);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but route is not hitting controller. It is showing 404 error before executing anything from the controller!

Comment: make sure you have no middleware added in controller 's constunctor and access index route

Comment: Yes. There is not middleware in the controller constructor.

Comment: how is this possible  `return redirect('/404')` it wont work `abort(404);` will work

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any mistake in your code.

My guess is you have a `route` above the `route` that you posted that is using the same url or you are using a `resourceful route` that also uses the same url.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, you need the following routes to work: -

```
domian.com/author/page/{username}
domian.com/author/page/{username}/{id}
```

First one is not working for you but second workes if you add `function index($username, $id)`

Follow below solution it will work or you: -

**Convert your route to**

```
Route::get('author/page/{username}/{id?}', 'FrontendAuthorController@index');
```

Which shows your route should have a `author name` and also can have `id` of the author. Id is options if you wouldn't provide it will still work.

**According to above add $id to function parameters too: -**

```
function index($username, $id)
```

**With this solution both of below url will work**

```
domian.com/author/page/rakesh
domian.com/author/page/rakesh/1
```

Comment: @MosharofZitu can you post how you define routes and then function, need to check missing component

Comment: might be you are having some conflicting routes then